# Django filter(icontains).extra produces wrong SQL syntax (no quotes)

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm, django-filter

I'm trying to build a custom query and would like to apply .extra() after filter(). The statement looks like:

```
V.objects.filter(v_id__product__icontains=name)
```

Now it produces the valid SQL, which, however, does not have quotes around name:

```
WHERE `v_id`.`product` LIKE %xxx%
```

But when I add .extra() statement:

```
V.objects.filter(id__product__icontains=name).extra(where=[concat_str],params=[version,'%','%'])
```

, the query becomes invalid because there is no quotes aroung %xxx%:

```
WHERE `v_id`.`product` LIKE %xxx% AND 'yyy' LIKE CONCAT('%',version,'%')
```

All I need here is to add single quotes around %xxx%, to make it valid:

```
WHERE `vulnerabilities_cpeid`.`product` LIKE '%xxx%' AND 'yyy' LIKE CONCAT('%',version,'%')
```

However, I just do not know how to force Django to put %xxx% into single quotes when using icontains. Any help appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Full traceback:

```
INFO 2014-07-21 11:33:55,515 views: SELECT `vulnerabilities_vulnerability`.`identifier` FROM `vulnerabilities_vulnerability` INNER JOIN `vulnerabilities_vulnerability_cpe_id` ON (`vulnerabilities_vulnerability`.`id` = `vulnerabilities_vulnerability_cpe_id`.`vulnerability_id`) INNER JOIN `vulnerabilities_cpeid` ON (`vulnerabilities_vulnerability_cpe_id`.`cpeid_id` = `vulnerabilities_cpeid`.`id`) WHERE (`vulnerabilities_cpeid`.`product` LIKE %accountsservice%  AND '0.6.15-2ubuntu9.7' LIKE CONCAT('%',version,'%'))
ERROR 2014-07-21 11:33:55,517 django.request: Internal Server Error: /vulndb/inventory/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sapegin/vulndb_mercurial/vulndb/HANA/PYTHON/Python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/sapegin/vulndb_mercurial/vulndb/vulndb/vulnerabilities/views.py", line 1650, in inventory
    if ((vulnerabilities is not None) and (vulnerabilities.count() > 0)):
  File "/home/sapegin/vulndb_mercurial/vulndb/HANA/PYTHON/Python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 351, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/home/sapegin/vulndb_mercurial/vulndb/HANA/PYTHON/Python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 418, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using=using)[None]
  File "/home/sapegin/vulndb_mercurial/vulndb/HANA/PYTHON/Python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 384, in get_aggregation
    result = query.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/home/sapegin/vulndb_mercurial/vulndb/HANA/PYTHON/Python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/sapegin/vulndb_mercurial/vulndb/HANA/PYTHON/Python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/sapegin/vulndb_mercurial/vulndb/HANA/PYTHON/Python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 119, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/sapegin/vulndb_mercurial/vulndb/HANA/PYTHON/Python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/sapegin/vulndb_mercurial/vulndb/HANA/PYTHON/Python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
DatabaseError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0.6.15-2ubuntu9.7'' LIKE CONCAT(''%'',version,''%''))' at line 1")
ERROR 2014-07-21 11:33:55,517 django.request: Internal Server Error: /vulndb/inventory/
```

Comment: Django would put quotes around the `%xxx%` afterwards, you cannot see this in the `.query`. What error do you get?

Comment: I get "DatabaseError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;...". And if I copy the string produced with .query, add quotes manually and then execute it in the mysql console, I do not get any errors.

Comment: Please include the complete traceback into the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the error is that you have extra quotes in your .extra call's parameters. Remove the quotes around %s and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Django the DatabaseWrapper will automatically add quotes there. The 'icontains' operator is translated to  `'icontains': 'LIKE %s'`, where `%s` will be replaced with the string which is concatenated with % signs before and after the search term.

Internally Django will use the `quote_name` function to do the quotation marks.

```
def quote_name(self, name):
    if name.startswith("`") and name.endswith("`"):
        return name # Quoting once is enough.
    return "`%s`" % name
```

Maybe for your use-case the raw Query might be a better Solution:

`Model.objects.raw('Select .... FROM .... WHERE ....', params=None, translations=None)`

Have a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

I think alecxe is right the debug in `.query` is not sufficient.